# Quantum Serre relations and braided commutator.

Tags: hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, nichols-algebras

I am reading the [lecture notes](http://www.famaf.unc.edu.ar/~andrus/colloquium-chicago07.pdf). On page 21, it is said that when $a_{ij}=-1$, we have
\begin{align}
ad_c(x_i)^{1-a_{ij}}(x_j)=x_i^2x_j - (q+q^{-1})x_ix_jx_i+x_jx_i^2. \quad (1)
\end{align}
Here $ad_c(x_i)(x_j)=x_ix_j - q^{a_{ij}}x_jx_x$.
I am trying to verify $(1)$. We have
\begin{align}
& ad_c(x_i)^{1-a_{ij}}(x_j)\\
& =ad_c(x_i)^{2}(x_j) \\
& =ad_c(x_i)(x_ix_j - q^{-1}x_jx_i) \\
& = x_i^2 x_j -q^{-1}x_ix_jx_i -q^{-1}( x_ix_j - q^{-1}x_jx_i )x_i \\
& = x_i^2 x_j -2q^{-1}x_ix_jx_i + q^{-2}x_jx_i^2.
\end{align}
But I didn't get $x_i^2x_j - (q+q^{-1})x_ix_jx_i+x_jx_i^2$. I don't know where I made a mistake. Thank you very much.

Comment: You haven't copied the equation correctly.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, $[2]_q=q+q^{-1}$.

Comment: The equation starts with $x_i^2 x_j$.

Comment: @LJR: where (in the paper you are citing) is the definition of $[2]_q$ ?

Comment: @KonKan, it is not defined in the paper. But it is quantum integer, see [for example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354188/arithmetic-with-quantum-integers).

Comment: @LJR I see that you have created ([tag:nichols-algebras]) tag. It might be useful to create also [tag-wiki or at least tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/nichols-algebras/info). It might help other users to use the tag correctly. (This is probably not a problem here, since the tag name seems to be descriptive enough.) Another reason is that the tags used on only one question are [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info) after certain time [unless they have tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $a_{ij}=-1$, 
\begin{align}
& ad_\Psi(x_i)^{1-a_{ij}}(x_j) \\
& = ad_c(x_i)^2(x_j) \\
& = ad_c(x_i)(x_i \otimes x_j - K_i.(x_j) \otimes x_i) \\
& = ad_c(x_i)(x_i \otimes x_j - q^{-1} x_j \otimes x_i) \\
& =  x_i \otimes x_i \otimes x_j - K_i.(x_i \otimes x_j) \otimes x_i - q^{-1} ( x_i \otimes x_j \otimes x_i - K_i.(x_j \otimes x_i) \otimes x_i) \\
& =  x_i \otimes x_i \otimes x_j - K_i.x_i \otimes K_i.x_j \otimes x_i - q^{-1} ( x_i \otimes x_j \otimes x_i - K_i.x_j \otimes K_i.x_i \otimes x_i) \\
& =  x_i \otimes x_i \otimes x_j - q^2 x_i \otimes q^{-1} x_j \otimes x_i - q^{-1} ( x_i \otimes x_j \otimes x_i - q^{-1} x_j \otimes q^2 x_i \otimes x_i) \\
& =  x_i \otimes x_i \otimes x_j - q x_i \otimes x_j \otimes x_i - q^{-1}  x_i \otimes x_j \otimes x_i +  x_j \otimes x_i \otimes x_i \\
& =  x_i \otimes x_i \otimes x_j - (q+q^{-1}) x_i \otimes x_j \otimes x_i +  x_j \otimes x_i \otimes x_i.
\end{align}

Comment: it seems to work! +1. So $K_i$ is not a scalar here? and it acts by comultiplication ? In which Hopf algebra does it belong to ?

Comment: @KonKan, $K_i$ is an element in a Hopf algebra. $\Delta(K_i) = K_i \otimes K_i$. $K_i.(u \otimes v) = K_i.u \otimes K_i.v$. The Hopf algebra is a group algebra.

Comment: @KonKan, in Example 2.6 in [the paper](http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~iheckenb/na.pdf), $K_i$ is denoted by $e^{\alpha_i}$.

Comment: ok I got it. +1. thanks for clarifying and providing the reference. P.S.: This thing should have been provided in the OP. In any case, I feel that the sign of acceptance for the correct answer rightfully belongs to your answer. If you would like to give me some credit for trying to help, an upvote should be enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making a mistake in the fourth line of your computation: you compute $-q^{-1}ad_c(x_i)\big(x_j\big)x_i \ $, instead of the correct:
$\ -q^{-1}ad_c(x_i)\big(x_jx_i\big)$. However, it seems that it does not affect the final result. Here's what I get:
\begin{align}
& ad_c(x_i)^{1-a_{ij}}(x_j)=\\
& =ad_c(x_i)^{2}(x_j)= \\
& =ad_c(x_i)(x_ix_j - q^{-1}x_jx_i)= \\
& = x_i^2 x_j -q^{-1}x_ix_jx_i -q^{-1}ad_c(x_i)\big(x_jx_i\big)= \\
& = x_i^2 x_j -q^{-1}x_ix_jx_i-q^{-1}\big(x_ix_jx_i-q^{-1}x_jx_i^2\big)= \\
& = x_i^2 x_j -q^{-1}x_ix_jx_i-q^{-1}x_ix_jx_i+q^{-2}x_jx_i^2 = \\
& = x_i^2 x_j -2q^{-1}x_ix_jx_i+q^{-2}x_jx_i^2
\end{align}
but it's still different from the result of the paper. Maybe there's some typo in the paper.

It is interesting to note that the two expressions 
$$
x_i^2 x_j -2q^{-1}x_ix_jx_i+q^{-2}x_jx_i^2
$$
and
$$
x_i^2x_j - (q+q^{-1})x_ix_jx_i+x_jx_i^2
$$
coincide if $q=q^{-1}$. (However, in such cases, $q$ is customarily considered **not to be** a root of unity).

Hope that helps a bit.